# Python awkward bash string export Bug

Tags: python, bash, scripting, grep

I've a problem recently, that Im not really capable to solve..

Here is a script

```
!/bin/bash

ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

The export will be simply your own IP Address

> 192.168.2.1

So far so good but then I go in Python and write

```
str(os.system("./GrabOwnIP.sh"))
```

I'll get a different output

> 192.168.2.1
>
> 0

I just want a variable thats keeping this information itself but then I write

```
OWNIP = str(os.system("./GrabOwnIP.sh"))
```

Then it will just give me

> 0

I also tried to use the line from the bash script itself in the Python one but the same results occured

Comment: What does this have to do with `export`? `export` is for creating environment variables that are inherited by child processes. Your question is about output, not export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system()` returns the exit code. Use `subprocess.check_output` to capture the standard output of the command.